# Request with large header failing

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I have rails app running on Nginx/Unicorn/Ubuntu. Nginx is setup with Unicorn as an upstream as follows:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/path/to/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

and

```
location @unicorn {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}
```

Everything works except one type of request. The page is trying to save HTML to the database. As such it's a large request. The request is passed to unicorn and the HTML is saved to the database, but then the page shows a 502 error. I checked the nginx logs and this shows up:

```
epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream
```

I've tried to increase the proxy buffer size with the following:

```
http {
  ...
  proxy_buffer_size 128k;
  proxy_buffers 4 256k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  ...
}
```

But the problem persists.

Any idea why this is happening and how to resolve?

Comment: Isn't it response timeout? How long does it takes?

Comment: I see the 502 in less than a second.